# changing a css :before if and ID has a specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so im trying to make Jquery change a specific css to a :before if a div has a spefic class

```
<ul>
 <li id="first" class="active">first</li>
 <li id="second">second</Li>
</ul>
```

if the first li is active i want the :before of the Ul to have a specific left and right properties but if the second li is active it will have a diffrent left and right
im adding the classes with Jquery and i tried to do something like this

```
if ( $( "#first" ).is( "active" )) {
  $('ul[data-style-id='slider1']:before').append('<style>.left:175px;right:1188px;}</style>');
}
```

edit:
i have a jquery code that gives it the left and right properties but it dosent work only for the first one so i tried to do a diffrent script to change only the first since that dident worked i tried to give it properties like in the answer but with the specific properties for each LI but again it dosent work... it only reads the first

https://jsfiddle.net/czf9kjfd/7/

in here it works great but in my browser it dosent work so my question is how can i define a specific left and right parameters if the first link is selected

Comment: I don't think you can directly style a pseudo element style via javascript.

Comment: pseudo elements (:before and :after) are not part of the DOM, therefore you cannot manipulate them using jQuery (or native JS)

Comment: Nor can content be appended to them.

Comment: can i use jqurey to just add css to overwrite the current css?

Comment: try to create a different css classes for each "left and right properties" and then append or remove them to/from an object via jQuery (or native JS)

Comment: Are those left/right values you want to set calculated dynamically? If they are not, but are just fixed, then they should rather be in your stylesheet to begin with.

Comment: What does trigger the `.active` on the `<li>`? If possible, use the same call to add a class on the `<ul>` too (e.g `.contains_first_li_active`), then in your CSS set up your `ul.contains_first_li_active::before{}` as you wish. (yes you can edit pseudo elements through js, but it's a nightmare seriously, don't bother with such hacks.)

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
if( $('ul li').hasClass('active') ) {
   $('head').append('<style>ul:before{left:175px !important;right:1188px !important;}</style>');
}
```

To add active class in hover

```
$("ul li").hover(function () {
   $(this).addClass("active");
},function(){
   $(this).removeClass("active");
 });
```

Comment: this works for when the first li is clicked but it just makes it as if it allways has the class active.. any idea why?

Comment: It's going to work if the first li has "active" class, If you want to add active class name when you just press it this is another case. as for a question I think it is the solution. use this edit

Comment: You would have to remove this script tag to disable its effects... (or use its `disabled` property when available)

Comment: i have a jquery code that gives it the left and right properties but it dosent work only for the first one so i tried to do a diffrent script to change only the first
since that dident worked i tried to give it properties like in the answer but with the specific properties for each LI but again it dosent work... it only reads the first

Comment: Cuz active class added in first li only, you need another Jquery lines to add active class in hover

Comment: Add this new lines to add active class to li

Comment: $ele.find("li").on("click", function () {
                  var $li = $(this),
                      CurrentIndex = $ele.find(".active").removeClass("active").index(),
                      ClickedIndex = $li.addClass("active").index();
the class changes but the :before properties dosent

Comment: the :before properties for ul or li ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need jQuery in this at all, it can be done via simple CSS:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li id="first" class="line-item active">first</li>
<li id="second" class="line-item">second</Li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.line-item { /* Styles */ }
.line-item::before { /* Styles */ }
.line-item.active { /* Styles */ }
.line-item.active::before {
  left: 175px !important;
  right: 1188px !important;
}
```

The `.line-item` class is just for a constant reference.

Hope it helps!

Comment: the prolbem with this is that when i click the second li i cant change it properties which is something that is suppoused to happen